# Gluing local holomorphic connections

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

On page $180$ of Complex Geometry by Daniel Huybrecths, he defines the so called Atiyah class of a holomorphic vector bundle by the Čech cocycle $$A(E)=\{U_{ij}, \psi^{-1}_j \circ (\psi^{-1}_{ij}d\psi_{ij}) \circ \psi_j\},$$ where $\psi_i: E|_{U_i}\cong U_i \times \Bbb C^r$ is a local trivialization and $\psi_{ij}$ the transition functions.

He then goes on to prove Proposition $4.2.19$ which states that a holomorphic vector bundle $E$ admits a holomorphic connection if and only if $A(E)=0$.

In the proof of this proposition its being stated that local holomorphic connections on $U_i \times \Bbb C^r$ are of the form $\partial + A_i$. This sounds all good to me, but then he states that on $U_{ij}$ these glue if and only if $$\psi_i^{-1}\circ (d+A_i) \circ \psi_i = \psi_j^{-1}\circ (d+A_j) \circ \psi_j.$$

This is an equation that does not really make sense to me. I've been taught that these local connections glue if and only if they satisfy $$A_j=\psi_{ij}^{-1}d\psi_{ij}+\psi^{-1}_{ij}A_i\psi_{ij}$$ which makes sense as this is only matrix multiplication. Is there some identification going on with the first equation I should be aware of or how is this derived (I was not able to go from the latter to this)? I tried to ask this on math.stackexchange before, but did not get any replies so apologies if this is not an appropriate question for this site.

Comment: This is a very obscure way to define the Atiyah class. A better way is defined in the same way as in https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09DC

Comment: @Z.M Richness of geometry comes from the variety of ways a given problem can be viewed. I'm not sure judging one particular viewpoint to be "obscure" or "better" serves any purpose here. Sharing your preferences and insights is great, but maybe you could phrase in a more open way.

Comment: It also seems rather over the top to call a definition obscure when it occurs in Atiyah's original paper as being equivalent to the definition he uses, see the proof of Theorem 5 in Atiyahs "Complex Analytic Connections in Fibre Bundles".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(*Updated, as I realized the formula stated by Huybrechts indeed also does make sense without making any identifications.*)

One should interpret the two sides in the compatibility condition of Huybrechts as defining two morphisms taking sections of $E$ to sections of $E \otimes \Omega^1$, i.e., if $\xi$ is a section of $E$ (over $V \subseteq U_i \cap U_j$), then the morphism on the left-hand side is
$$\xi \mapsto\psi_i^{-1} ((d + A_i) (\psi_{i} \xi)),$$
which does indeed make sense as $\psi_i \xi$ is a section of $V \times \mathbb{C}^r$. By a similar calculation as the one in Huybrechts after equation (4.4), one may show that this condition is equivalent to the compatibility condition that you write. I suppose Huybrechts has written it the way he did since he had not stated the compatibility condition that you write earlier in the text.

If one starts with your equation for compatibility, then one may compose this with $\psi_j^{-1}$ from the left and $\psi_j$ from the right, which yields
$$
\psi_j^{-1} \psi_{ij}^{-1} d\psi_{ij} \psi_j = \psi_j^{-1} A_j \psi_j - \psi_i^{-1} A_i \psi_i
$$
and then conclude the proof as in the last paragraph of Proposition 4.2.19. This would make the proof a bit shorter, but relies on the fact that one knows this equation for compatibility.

Comment: I think I might have some idea on what is happening here. Huybrecths is describing holomorphic connections as maps of sheaves $\nabla : E \to \Omega_X \otimes E$, where $\Omega_X$ is the holomorphic cotangent bundle. Could this be the reason for why the formula would make sense? @richard-lärkäng

Comment: No, I don't think it has to do with what viewpoint you have of connections. I think it is a minor mistake of Huybrechts, but which as I described may be easily corrected, and which actually makes the proof shorter than what he has written.

Comment: Right, okay. In view of this I think I should also adjust the definition of the Atiyah class? @richard-lärkäng

Comment: No, I think the definition of the Atiyah class is fine. (The issue is that $d\psi_i$ and $d\psi_j^{-1}$ do not have any intrinsic meaning, but $d\psi_{ij}$ does.)

Comment: I meant changing it to $A(E)=\{U_{ij}, \psi^{-1}_j(\psi^{-1}_{ij}d\psi_{ij})\psi_j\},$ since if I understood your answer, we are now identifying the trivializations $\psi_i: E|_{U_i}\to U_i \times \Bbb C^r$ with the matrices of the linear maps $f_{\psi_i}:E_p \to \Bbb C^r$ obtained from $$\psi_i(p,v)=(p, f_{\psi_i}(v)).$$ Sorry for being overly pedantic, I just really want to understand the identifications going on here. @richard-lärkäng

Comment: Sorry, I realized that there is a reasonable interpretation of what Huybrechts wrote. I have now updated my answer. Anyhow, there is no identification of the $\psi_i$ as matrices, just as linear maps.

Comment: Thanks for updating this. It clears things up for me. About regarding $\psi_i$'s as matrices, equation 4.4 states $$\psi^{-1}_i \circ \partial \circ \psi_i -\psi^{-1}_j \circ \partial \circ \psi_j =  \psi^{-1}_jA_j\psi_j -\psi^{-1}_iA_i\psi_i,$$ where the compositions on the left-hand side are compositions of linear maps, but I thought that these products on the rhs are matrix products which would indeed mean that $\psi_i$'s are identified as matrices. Is this just being lazy and dropping the composition symbol? @richard-lärkäng

Comment: I would not read anything like that into the missing composition symbol. When you compose linear maps, there is no ambiguity, so you may include or skip the composition symbol as you wish. For the parts involving $d$ (or $\partial$), it makes sense to include the composition symbol to give it the meaning that I wrote in my answer, while without the composition symbol, it would seem natural to me to interpret it as $d$ acting $\psi_i$, but as mentioned above, this has no reasonable meaning if one does not identify $\psi_i$ with a matrix, which you cannot do in an intrinsic way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer my rather elementary questions. I'm quite new to the topic. @richard-lärkäng

Comment: One more question, in $\xi \mapsto\psi_i^{-1} ((d + A_i) (\psi_{i} \xi))$ do you identify $\psi^{-1}_i : V \times \Bbb C^r \to E|_{V}$ with a map $$\psi^{-1}_i : \Omega^1 \otimes (V \times \Bbb C^r) \to \Omega^1 \otimes E|_{V}$$ that sends $\omega \otimes s \mapsto \omega \otimes \psi^{-1}_i(s)$, since $(d + A_i) (\psi_{i} \xi)$ is a section of $\Omega^1 \otimes (V \times \Bbb C^r)$? @richard-lärkäng

Comment: Indeed, if one wants to be really precise, the map is not $\psi_i^{-1}$, but $Id \otimes \psi_i^{-1}$.